# Mysql: How can i join two tables and find the revenue of each company for latest year

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

**This is Two tables with data, how to  join both these tables and find the revenue of each
company for the latest available year.** How can I write SQL query to get expected result?

```
  Table ‘Companies’:

    Id | companyCode| companyName
    1 | comp1      | Tata Motors
    2 | comp2      | Reliance
    3 | comp3      | Infosys
    4 | comp4      | HDFCBANK

 Table ‘FinancialDatas’

   Id | companyCode| year | revenue
   12 | comp1      | 2019 | 12500
   13 | comp1      | 2020 | 13250
   14 | comp2      | 2018 | 45000
   15 | comp2      | 2019 | 55000
   16 | comp3      | 2019 | 9500
   17 | comp3      | 2020 | 7500
   18 | comp4      | 2017 | 11000
   19 | comp4      | 2018 | 13500

Extexted OutPut Below:

  companyName | year | revenue
  Tata Motors |2020  |13250
  Reliance    |2019  |55000
  Infosys     |2020  |7500
  HDFCBANK    |2018  |13500
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and publish what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select companyName,year,revenue,row_number() over(partition by companyName order by year desc) as rn
from companies c join FinancialDatas f on c.companycode=f.companycode
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: Thank You so much, it worked for me appreciated your help.

Comment: @Ajay, happy to help you. Please mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: how can remove displaying rn=1 in the result? as it is not required